# C++/Visual Studio 2005 - Template Class skipped during compilation of debug configuration

Tags: debugging, templates, visual-studio-2005, skip, vc8

I have a template class, which had always been able to be compiled in **Debug**, with no problems. All of a sudden though, it refuses to detect changes to the class and skips it, unless I Rebuild. There's no problem with other non-template classes, and this problem doesn't occur when compiling in **Release**, so I'm just using that for now.

The weird thing is, I've created a new project, and the same problem occurs.

Any ideas?

Thanks lots. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Problem - at least with visual studio. Sometimes it always rebuilds. Sometimes it fails to rebuild. There is a number of things you may check:

One might be "Enable minimal rebuild" which you can disable in 
Project->Properties->C/C++->Code generation.

As th problem does only occur in debug mode this might be the problem.

Other problems may occur if a .obj file has a date in the future - but this should disappear after a first rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried disabling minimal rebuild, and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!